# How to decide whether property or method to use in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

Creating a static class to write unit test. I'm not sure whether the static property or static method to use.

Please see the code below and advise me.

1) MailParterDummies ( the one with static property)

```
public static class MailPartnerDummies
{
    public static IEnumerable<MailingPartner> MailingPartners
    {
        get
        {
            int index = 0;
            IList<MailingPartner> mailingPartners = new List<MailingPartner>();
            for (int i = 0; i < _text.Count(); i++)
            {
                var mailingPartner = new MailingPartner();

                index = index > _text.Count() ? 0 : index;

                mailingPartner.MailingPartnerID = i + 1;
                mailingPartner.ContactName = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.OrganisationName = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.FullAddress = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.Town = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.County = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.Country = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.PostalZipCode = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.TelephoneNumber = i + 1;
                mailingPartner.EmailAddress = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.WebsiteAddress = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.AddedOn = DateTime.Now;
                mailingPartner.AddedBy = _text[index];
                mailingPartner.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                mailingPartner.UpdatedBy = _text[index];

                mailingPartners.Add(mailingPartner);
                index ++;
            }

            return mailingPartners;
        }
    }



    #region fake variables

    private readonly static string[] _text = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };

    #endregion
}
```

2) MailParterDummies ( the one with static method)

```
public static class MailPartnerDummies
{        
    public static IEnumerable<MailingPartner> MailingPartnerList()
    {
        int index = 0;
        IList<MailingPartner> mailingPartners = new List<MailingPartner>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _text.Count(); i++)
        {
            var mailingPartner = new MailingPartner();

            index = index > _text.Count() ? 0 : index;

            mailingPartner.MailingPartnerID = i + 1;
            mailingPartner.ContactName = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.OrganisationName = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.FullAddress = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.Town = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.County = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.Country = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.PostalZipCode = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.TelephoneNumber = i + 1;
            mailingPartner.EmailAddress = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.WebsiteAddress = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.AddedOn = DateTime.Now;
            mailingPartner.AddedBy = _text[index];
            mailingPartner.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            mailingPartner.UpdatedBy = _text[index];

            mailingPartners.Add(mailingPartner);
            index++;
        }

        return mailingPartners;
    }


    #region fake variables

    private readonly static string[] _text = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };

    #endregion
}
```

Shall I use 1) or 2) ?
Thanks.

Comment: You're writing this to back a test, so I would go with what makes the test more readable.

Comment: Its does not matter in your case use whatever you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the method.

According to Microsoft's Rico Mariani, properties should never do anything else besides returning the requested value. If you need to to any data processing, which you do in your example, use methods.

By doing this you clearly communicate to the calling code there is some work being done under the hoods.

Have a look at Rico's article: [Performance Guidelines for Properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2011/12/19/performance-guidelines-for-properties.aspx)

Quote:

> So, you’re using a property, the most important thing to remember is
> that it will seem very much like a field in all ways.  It looks like a
> field and feels like a field, people will expect it to perform like a
> field.  So with that in mind:
>
> - Accessing the property should not allocate any memory; people are going to use this thing in loops walking over whatever data structure
>   you are presenting, they expect that this data is sitting around and
>   being accessed.
> - Accessing the property should not “synchronize” – if there is any locking to be done it should be done at a higher level than a single
>   field, by the time you’ve acquired whatever object has the property on
>   it, it should already be safe to read it.
> - Accessing the property should not do any I/O, especially not any network I/O, again see above, by the time you’re reading the property
>   the object offering it should have done whatever I/O was needed.
> - Accessing the property should not be an operation with complexity greater than O(1) – that means no loops.  At all.  You could haggle me
>   as high as O(lg(N)) if we’re talking about an property that is an
>   “indexer” but no higher.
>   Accessing the property should not have side-effects (i.e. it's strictly a read operation, it changes nothing)
>
> What you’re left with is you can use your object state and the
> argument (if an indexer) to do a constant-time lookup, or log-time at
> worst, in an already existing data structure and immediately return
> the result.  That’s it.